# How do I add syntax keywords globally for any filetype?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have some keywords other than TODO used in comments that are common to all languages, things like 'NOTE'.

I want to label these words under Todo syntax class, so that they have the same colour with TODO, but I don't know how to do it globally. Adding the following line to my vimrc doesn't work.

```
syntax keyword Todo contained NOTE
```

Does anyone know how to do it globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd Syntax * syntax keyword Todo contained NOTE
```

If you want this to work in comments for almost any syntax:

```
autocmd Syntax * syntax keyword Todo NOTE containedin=.*Comment
```

I don't remember where it's documented, but `containedin=` can be a pattern.  Most syntaxes use the `Comment` suffix for comment groups.

Comment: The first command doesn't work, but the second works! However, I have to remove .*Cmnt part to suppress some error saying the group doesn't exist. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Stone Are you sure the first one doesn't work? I tested it and it works as long as a syntax has a group with `contains=Todo`.  I assumed that was your aim.  I guess I didn't notice the error when I tested the second one.  I'll remove it from the post.