# List of Vimscript comment keyword highlights

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

While editing my `vimrc` I noticed that some keywords get highlighted at the beginning of lines, like `Note:` and `Reminder:`. I tried to find this syntax group in the `vim.vim` syntax file, but to no avail. I also looked through all the `:help` files I could think of. Does anyone have a complete list of these handy keywords? Which syntax file are they located in?

This question references a similar type of keyword that might be in the same list, if these words are not limited to Vimscript:

[How do I add syntax keywords globally for any filetype?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/how-do-i-add-syntax-keywords-globally-for-any-filetype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look through `:syn list` we see some elements which are the same color as the highlighted words, in particular, `vimCommentTitle`.  Using `:syn list vimCommentTitle` we see:

```
vimCommentTitle xxx match /"\s*\%([sS]:\|\h\w*#\)\=\u\w*\(\s\+\u\w*\)*:/hs=s+1  
contained contains=vimCommentTitleLeader,vimTodo,@vimCommentGroup
               links to PreProc
```

So the list of words is given by a regex, roughly:

- Word:
- s:Word:
- S:Word:
- He Llo World:
- Hello#World:

and so on.

The purpose of this seems to be highlighting sections and function names in a vim script (although the pattern does not cover all possible function names).  For example:

```
" Some Functions: {{{

" module#Function: this surely does something
fu! module#Function()
endf

" s:Func2: this does something privately
fu! s:Func2()
endf

" }}}
```

Comment: `:echo synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')` is pretty useful to get the name of whatever is under the cursor (I have it as a command, since it's a bit hard to remember/type), then use `:verbose hi <name>` to find out where it was defined. Probably a bit easier than scanning through `:syn list` :-)

Comment: These are both very helpful, it will make it much easier to tweak highlighting.